# Convert time to different timezone with jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetime, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I have a time and date in the "Zulu" time zone (which is  the same time zone as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC))

I need to convert this time and date into the Central time zone using jQuery.

Right now Im attempting to use "Moment Timezone" since I already use "Moment" and it seems like Timezone is capable of what I need but the documentation is sparse.

I thought this would work but it returns "Monday, January 20 2014 1:03 AM" without converting the time

```
var stampString='January 20 2014 01:03';
var m = moment(stampString);
var convertedTime=m.tz("CST6CDT").format('LLLL');
```

How can I accomplish what I need? Im open to using a different library if needed, possibly an ajax call to some php method? jQuery would be preferred though.

Comment: it would be easy if you use `php` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `CST6CDT`.  That is an old-style POSIX time zone.  They're only there for backwards compatibility purposes.  The correct zone for US Central Time is `America/Chicago`.  There's a section about POSIX time zones in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) if you want to learn more.

You'll also need to tell moment exactly what format you are using, and you'll want to tell it that it is being supplied in UTC.

```
var stampString = 'January 20 2014 01:03';
var m = moment.utc(stampString, "MMMM D YYYY HH:mm");
var convertedTime = m.tz("America/Chicago").format('LLLL');
```