# How to convert between time zones using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable in jQuery which stores a time-stamp that was returned from an API call

```
var timestamp = "Fri Apr 1 15:59:00 UTC-04:00 2016";
```

How do I convert it to Pacific Time in this format (01 April 2016, 12:59:00 pm) which is my local time zone?

Comment: I recommend http://momentjs.com

Comment: try this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451998/convert-time-to-different-timezone-with-jquery) in stack overflow