# How to convert utc timestamp to current time of another city?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I got timestamp utc of new york from weather api, want to display current time in New York but it gives output something like this 'UTC Sun Dec 01 2019 05:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'. 
See the code for reference

```
  // Code 1
  //I get timestamp_utc when console.log(data)
  //timestamp_utc: "2019-12-01T05:00:00"
  const utc = new Date(data.timestamp_utc)

  console.log('UTC', utc)
  // UTC Sun Dec 01 2019 05:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)


  // Code 2
  // Another code for getting current time but, failed
var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: timezone}); // Here timezone is from props

console.log('USA time: '+usaTime) // USA time: 12/1/2019, 4:59:58 AM
```

I also have timezone data getting from weather API. My aim is to get current time based on timezone or utc timestamp. As you can see both my trials are unsuccessful. Expected output is 6:39 PM which is now current time in New York. Is there any  good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with your 'code 2'.  This is the same as what you wrote but with the timezone filled in...

```
const timezone = "America/New_York";
const usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString( "en-US", { timeZone: timezone});
console.log( 'usaTime =', usaTime );
```

For me this works.  I get the current time in NY formatted correctly for USA.  I'm not sure why yours did not work but I wonder what you specified for the timezone string.

I also a bit puzzled by your 'Code 1'.  The 'new Date()' that you created is being converted to a string and then printed by your console.log statement, but this should result in a ISO 8601 string and you seem to be getting a locale string (the date format).

Answer (score 0):

Though the example string you gave is in ISO 8601 format, it is not explicitly UTC because it does not end with a `Z`, nor does it end with a time zone offset such as `+00:00`.  Thus when you parse it with the `Date` constructor, it is interpreted as *local time*.  You can fix this by adding the `Z` yourself (assuming the `timestamp_utc` field is consistently a string in that format):

```
// timestamp_utc: "2019-12-01T05:00:00"
const utc = new Date(data.timestamp_utc + 'Z');  // adding the Z forces parsing as UTC
```

Now you have a `Date` object.  However, if you just pass it to `console.log`, the output you see is implementation dependent.  You will either see the local time in the same format you'd get by calling `toString`,  or you will see the UTC time in the same format you'd get by calling `toISOString`.

To get the time in a different time zone, now you can call `toLocaleString` and pass the `timeZone` option.  This assumes that the time zone is a valid IANA time zone identifier, and that the environment where the code is running fully supports the time zone features of the ECMAScript Internationalization Specification (ECMA-402).  This is indeed the case with most modern browsers, but you will not get correct output in older browsers such as Internet Explorer.

```
const usEasternTime = utc.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 'America/New_York'});
```

Lastly from your variable name `usaTime`, I think perhaps you might be under the assumption that the US has a single time zone, but it does not.  You will need to pass the correct time zone identifier.  See [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score -1):

Define the time zones of origin ($ sourceDate) and destination (to convert).

```
$sourceTimeZone = 'utc';
$targetTimeZone = 'America/Bogota';
```

Separate the components of the date of origin that is in the format ‘m / d / y h: m: s’.

```
list($month, $day, $year, $hours, $minutes, $seconds) = sscanf($sourceDate, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%f");
```

Build the DateTime object indicating the date and time zone in which it is located.

```
$datetime = new DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-{$day} {$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}",
                         new DateTimeZone($sourceTimeZone));
```

Modify the time zone of the DateTime to the destination time zone.

```
$datetime -> setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($targetTimeZone));
```

Get the components of the new date with the modified time zone.

```
list($month2, $day2, $year2, $hours2, $minutes2, $seconds2) = sscanf($datetime -> format(‘m/d/Y H:i:s’), “%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%f”);
```

Show the dates.

```
echo "En {$sourceTimeZone}: {$day}/{$month}/{$year} {$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}<br/>";
echo "En {$targetTimeZone}: {$day2}/{$month2}/{$year2} {$hours2}:{$minutes2}:{$seconds2}<br/>";
```

PD: For JavaScript this can help you [Convert time to different timezone with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451998/convert-time-to-different-timezone-with-jquery)

Comment: Is this in JavaScript?

Comment: No, its php. Do you need in js?